# Divide PHP string into arrayed substrings based on "divider" characters

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, substring

What I'd like to do is split a PHP string into a set of sub-strings grouped into arrays based on "divider" characters that begin those sub-strings. The characters `*`, `^`, and `%` are reserved as divider characters. So if I have the string `"*Here's some text^that is meant*to be separated^based on where%the divider characters^are"`, it should be split up and placed in arrays like so:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => "*Here's some text"
    [1] => "*to be separated"
}

array(3) {
    [0] => "^that is meant"
    [1] => "^based on where"
    [2] => "^are"
}

array(1) {
    [0] => "%the divider characters" 
}
```

I'm totally lost on this one. Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried the explode() function ?

Comment: The programming term for "divider characters" is delimiters.

Comment: I wrote a custom sting tokenizer because I'm old and bored at work. https://gist.github.com/Sammitch/774677bb7e82e4c6e128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't ask for `$matches[0]` so unset it if you want:

```
preg_match_all('/(\*[^*^%]+)|(\^[^*^%]+)|(%[^*^%]+)/', $string, $matches);
$matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The `array_filter()` removes the empties from the capture group sub-arrays to give the array shown in the question

Comment: `array_map('array_filter'` really? why not `unset`?

Comment: `array_filter` to remove empties in the others.  That would be a loop and multiple unsets

Comment: Please remove excess escaping in negated character classes.  Good answer.